# How to convert time in 12 hr format?

Tags: android, datetime

I'm getting call time through a cursor and want to display it in 12 hr format instead of 24 hr format.

Here is my code to get time from a cursor

```
String callDate = managedCursor.getString(dateIndex);
Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
```

and set this call day time to text view by

```
lastintreactionvalueTV.setText(callDayTime+"");
```

it's showing it like

```
Thu Jun 26 14:36:24 EDT 2014
```

What should I do to convert it into 12 hr format?

Comment: check this SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM-DD HH:mm");
        dateFormat.format(callDayTime);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat to set the format that you need, for example:

```
    Date callDayTime  = new Date();
    DateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd KK:mm:ss a z yyyy",new Locale("en"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(callDayTime) );
```

This will output:

> Thu, Jun 26 08:54:51 AM CEST 2014

Comment: What do you say is wrong? Check this please: H Hour in day (0-23) Number 0
k Hour in day (1-24) Number 24
K Hour in am/pm (0-11) Number 0
h Hour in am/pm (1-12) Number 12 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: sush, from the java page: K Hour in am/pm (0-11)

Comment: sush please... review my answer before you downvote, its working as expected.

Comment: yup my mistake.. there is diff in k and K.. but i didnt downvoted you. at all.. i can upvote now.. thats all.

Comment: Thanks sush, I usually test my answers with a syso, I don't understand who has downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
 SimpleDateFormat read = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-dd-yy");
    String op = write.format(read.parse("2014-05-17 15:45:56"));
```

//

```
 SimpleDateFormat read = new SimpleDateFormat("input format");
    SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("output format");
    String op = write.format(read.parse("your date as in input format"));
```

Comment: i want to add same thing Thu Jun 26 14:36:24 EDT 2014 but want to change the time format only

Comment: SimpleDateFormat write = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-dd-yy");
you can define the output format here

Comment: how do i pass the string that i am getting from cursor